# Chrome - Highlight Links that open in new/same tab

Tags: google-chrome

before clicking on a link, I would like to know whether it will open in a new tab or in the same tab. Is there a way to display this information in some way? With a small symbol next to the link or by altering link colors or something similar.

Thank you!

Comment: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, etc" is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: It's still off-topic for StackOverflow. This time it's "About general computing hardware and software". In short, this is still not related to development. P.S. you don't need to appease me. I only commented because I thought it could be helpful to you. Normally such unsalvageable questions are closed without any comment.